# How to remove a group of same extension files in different folders

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal

I want to remove a group of same extension files with different file name in different folders from my pen drive, I tried with the following commend, but its not working.

```
$sudo find /media/<Pendrive> *.jpg | rm -rf *
```

could someone let me know the exact command to delete the files from my Pendrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
sudo find '/media/<Pendrive>' -name '*.jpg' -exec rm -f '{}' ';'
```

---

> okay, If I'm exporting all the file paths to a text file and now I want to delete the files by using awk commend would it be possible in this case.

If the text file is named `all_file_paths.txt`, then you can write:

```
while IFS= read -r file_to_delete ; do
  if [[ "$file_to_delete" == *.jpg ]] ; then
    sudo rm -f "$file_to_delete"
  fi
done < all_file_paths.txt
```

(where the command `IFS= read -r file_to_delete` reads one line from standard input — which in this case is coming from `all_file_paths.txt` — and stores that line in the variable `$file_to_delete`).

Note that this approach will misbehave if any file-paths contain the newline character. There's no reliable way around that, since you've already discarded the distinction between "end of file-path" and "newline inside file-path" when you created `all_file_paths.txt`.

Comment: okay, If I'm exporting all the file paths to a text file and now I want to delete the files by using awk commend would it be possible in this case.